# Python Flash read data / enumeration

Tags: gpio, python

I read in the datasheet that my Flash can be read by doing:

> To perform a read operation, RST# and WE# must be deasserted while CE# and OE# are asserted. CE# is the device-select control. When asserted, it enables the flash memory device. OE# is the data-output control. When asserted, the addressed flash memory data is driven onto the I/O bus.

So if I understand, I use GPIO to set pins state first and then read stuff after they're set. I'm trying to modify the code snippet below to do what I want. I think once I set the pins to the right state, I should be able to iterate through the addresses and read the data, but don't know Python enough to do that.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) # sets numbering system of GPIO pins
channel = MY_BOARD_PIN_ID

GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH) # output high

# wait for a few ms

GPIO.output(channel, GPIO.LOW) # output low

# maybe wait for a few ms

GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.IN) # change to input

# then some code where you read the input as many times as needed:
value = GPIO.input(channel)

# lastly
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: this is a python programming question, not a raspberry pi question ... you may get a quicker answer at a python related site

Comment: Thanks, I asked it over on stack overflow.